# dart: why local functions can not call each other?

Tags: flutter, dart, local-functions

```dart
// OK, it works!
void global_1() => global_2();
void global_2() => global_1();

void main() {
    // ERROR Local variable 'local_2' can't be referenced before it is declared.
    void local_1() => local_2(); // <=== ERROR
    void local_2() => local_1();
}
```

The compiler said *"The local variable can't be reference before it is declared"*

But why **global functions** can call each other recursively but **local functions** can not?

I need to know WHY and some good workarounds for this situation.

Comment: You could work around it by doing: `void Function() local_2; void local_1() => local_2(); local_2 = () => local_1();`

Comment: It compiles ok for me. [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/WUTkK9)

Comment: @PedroPerez But your fiddle is in C#, I said about dart

Answer (score 1):

I suspect it depends on scope.  `global_1` can call `global_2` because those are both valid for the duration of the app.  But `local_2` doesn't exist until it is declared, which is after it is used.